# Built-In Node Modules "could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules"

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am trying to build my application on XCode 14.2 using a MacBook with an Apple M1 chip. When I try building, I encounter this error (apologies for the link, I don't have enough reputation to post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J6Hn.png

*description for accessibility: "unable to resolve module stream from [path]... stream could not be found within the project or in these directories: node modules"*

The obvious solution is to run `yarn add stream` and restart my XCode emulator with a new build, however that leads me to receive the same error for every built-in node module I am using. I've tried running `yarn add` for all of the other modules (http, https, net, util, etc) to get rid of the errors, which then led me to this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kofy0.png

*description for accessibility: "While trying to resolve module `http` from file [path] was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`[local-path]/node_modules/http/index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
[path-to-http-module]/index.js..... [path-to-http-module]/index.js/index.js"*

This is my metro-config.js file:

```
@format

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
    sourceExts: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs']
  },
};
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "ipad-pro": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.271.0",
    "@aws-sdk/is-array-buffer": "^3.201.0",
    "@aws-sdk/util-buffer-from": "^3.208.0",
    "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-retry": "^3.4.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.11.10",
    "expo-network": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.3.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http2": "^3.3.7",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-a-beep": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-callkeep": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sound-recorder": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-gifted-chat": {
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

This is my PodFile:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Mobile' do
  use_expo_modules!

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

  config = use_native_modules!

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  
  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'react-native-twilio-video-webrtc', path: '../node_modules/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc'

  pod 'RNCallKeep', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-callkeep'

  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone"

  target 'MobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_flipper!()
  
  post_install do |installer|
    # flipper_post_install(installer)
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    

    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end

target 'tvOS' do

  target 'tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

I have tried the following:

1. deleting all node modules, deleting yarn.lock, running `yarn cache clean` and reinstalling all dependencies
2. running `pod disintegrate` and `pod repo update` followed by `pod install`
3. running `yarn add` for every build-in module that was throwing an error
4. manually adding an index.js file to my http and https modules
5. restarting my laptop, restarting VS Code, restarting XCode
6. adding '.cjs' to my source extensions in the metro-config.js file
7. gone through all related stack overflow questions